# How do I write a script in PowerShell to run Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 TFS "Get latest version"?

Tags: powershell, tfs

Does anyone know how to write a PowerShell script to automate the "Get latest Version" function of Team Foundation Server?

I have tried several examples however none have worked.

**Here is my code so far:**

```
#Load Reference Assemblies
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client")  
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client")  
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common")
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client")

Function Get-TFSLatestFromVersionControls
{
param
(
#FQDN to SCCM Server
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$YourServerPath = "$/DEV",
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$YourLocalPath = "C:\Project\DEV",
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$tfsCollectionUrl = "http://10.0.10.200:8080/tfs/collection"
)

#Delete the old local copy
if((Test-Path -Path ($YourLocalPath)) -eq 1 )
{
    Remove-Item -Path $YourLocalPath -Recurse
    New-Item -Path $YourLocalPath -Type directory
Read-Host -Prompt "Delete the old local copy"
}


#Get Team Project Collection
$teamProjectCollection = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($tfsCollectionUrl)

#enter a path to your tfs server
$tfsServer = $tfsCollectionUrl
 # get an instance of TfsTeamProjectCollection
$tfs=get-tfsserver $tfsServer
# get an instance of VersionControlServer
$vCS = $tfs.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer])
$TeamProject = $YourServerPath.Remove(0,2)
$tfsProject = $vcs.GetTeamProject($TeamProject)


$workspace = $vcs.GetWorkspace($YourLocalPath)
if($workspace -eq $null)
{
    $vcs.DeleteWorkspace("TFS-"+$env:COMPUTERNAME,$env:USERNAME)
    $workspace = $vcs.CreateWorkspace("TFS-"+$env:COMPUTERNAME, $env:USERNAME)
Read-Host -Prompt "Delete the old workspace"
}

$workspace.Map($YourServerPath, $YourLocalPath)

$workspace.Get([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionSpec]::Latest ,[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.GetOptions]::Overwrite)
Read-Host -Prompt "Get Latest"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Latest Version of Folder from TFS, using Powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22298359/get-latest-version-of-folder-from-tfs-using-powershell)

Comment: No the duplicate did not solve it

Comment: Have you tried writing any code? StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Show us what you have tried and we might be able to suggest solutions.

Comment: I have edited my post Mark

Comment: You could use  [Team Foundation Server Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MartinWoodward.TeamFoundationServerPowerToolsDecember2011), 
Open the Windows PowerShell console, and then load the Team Foundation cmdlets from the Visual Studio, then you can use version control. More details please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299908/get-latest-version-of-a-project-from-tfs-using-powershell

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this is installing [TFS PowerTools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MartinWoodward.TeamFoundationServerPowerToolsDecember2011) as Patrick mentioned and then you just need to use "`Update-TfsWorkspace`" command to get the latest version.
[image]

And if you want to get the latest via TFS API, refer to the code below for details:

```
$uri = "http://tfsurl:8080/tfs/collectionname/";
$workspacename = "workspacename"
$tfs = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($uri)
$vcs = $tfs.GetService("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer")
$workspaces = $vcs.QueryWorkspaces($workspacename,"","")
$workspace = $workspaces | Select-Object -First 1
$workspace.Get();
```